# Using Login in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

In MVC 5 I use to implement the Login, the Logout as well as ExternalLogin and Callback methods. Now I'm trying to follow microsoft guides but they are not showing up in the templates and I'm rather confused. I don't see a login or account controller yet when I got to account/login page it loads. What is going on here? I can't seem to find information on this.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm looking to build a controller that will handle the login as I need additional processing logic implemented. Razor Pages would not work for me. Where can I find code examples on how to achieve this?

Comment: I use this link in my asp.net core 2.2 app as a help https://github.com/TanvirArjel/AspNetCoreMvcIdentity   might help you as well

Comment: @MuhammadAli that was very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with ASP.NET Core 2.1, the UI for sign-in and registration is contained in the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI).

You can instead include the files in your project by following this guide: [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).

The guide has more detailed instructions for various scenarios, but for an empty project, from Visual Studio:

> - From Solution Explorer, right-click on the project > Add > New Scaffolded Item.
> - From the left pane of the Add Scaffold dialog, select Identity > ADD.
> - In the ADD Identity dialog, select the options you want.
>
>   - Select your existing layout page, or your layout file will be overwritten with incorrect markup. For example
>       `~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` for Razor Pages
>       `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` for MVC projects
>   - Select the + button to create a new Data context class.
> - Select ADD.

Or from the CLI:

```
# install the scaffolder tool
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator

# add the code generation NuGet package to your project
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
dotnet restore

dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --useDefaultUI
```

Comment: That was useful however, i'm still stuck as I need the code that would go in the controller typically. This generated razor pages which are not overly helpful to me as they contain no logic.

Comment: The Identity.UI package uses Razor pages (not MVC, so there's no controller), you can find the logic [in the source for version 3.0.0 of the package](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/aee5e4080331553ea9dfb7fb388b6d72f715bf6a/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V3/Account) and copy it into your own controller.

Comment: I tested adding the scaffolded pages in VS2019 16.3.5, and it copies both the Razor layout file and the backing .cs file into the project. There should be a disclosure triangle next to the Razor page to display the C# file.